# How to hide icons from ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm looking to hide a icons from the ActionBar depending on variables. Is there a simple way to do this?

Will I need to use `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide menu items you should use the `setVisible()` method on your menu item inside your activity `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` override after your menu has been inflated. For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.example, menu);

    if(showItem) {

        menu.findItem(R.id.icon).setVisible(true);

    } else {

        menu.findItem(R.id.icon).setVisible(false);

    }

    return true;

}
```

If you have declared your variable inside `onCreate()`, it will be limited to the scope of `onCreate()` and therefore inaccessible inside `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`.

For example, instead of this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    boolean showItem = false;
    // ...
}
```

Declare it like this:

```
public boolean showItem = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
}
```

Also if you want to change the visibility on button press for example, you will need to call the `invalidateOptionsMenu()` method to reload the menu.

Comment: Alright so this works, but only on onCreate(). So it won't react to the variable being changed

Comment: @Tom Call `Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu` to indicate that the options menu should be recreated.

Comment: Well you know Java confines the scope of the variable to the method. I assume you have the variable declared in onCreate which limits the scope of the variable to the onCreate method, so you need to declare it in the activity class, before the onCreate method.

Comment: I updated the answer to help clarify this for you. Also, as @adneal stated if you want to change this on button press for example you will need to call invalidateOptionsMenu() to update it.

Comment: My variables are not inside of onCreate. I need to figure out how to use invalidateOptionsMenu()

Comment: invalidateOptionsMenu() is a method of the activity, so you can just call it from anywhere inside the activity. If you post your full code I can help you with this, but if this answer helped you please accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: It's working. I put that if statement into the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` method rather than the `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. So you may need to edit your answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` depending on your variable.

When you call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` will be called , where you can hide/show the option menu like this..

```
 @Override
 public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

  for(int index = 0 ; index < menu.size() ; index ++){
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(index);
    if(menuItem != null) {
        // hide the menu items 
        menuItem.setVisible(false);
    }
    }
   return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
  }
```

Comment: So how do I call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` ? Do I do it when the variable should change?